# How to give a 5GB video file to a friend, so that it'll play on their TV?

Tags: mac, video, usb-flash-drive, formatting, tv

I have a `.mov` that I'd like to bring to an event and show people. It is 5.33 GB and I have it on my Mac. I have a 16GB flash drive, and the host has a TV with USB input. I'd like to get that file onto that drive, in the format that will most likely work when plugged into the TV.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most TVs with this type of functionality would understand a FAT32 drive.  This means making the movie file size less then 4GB.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the answer. Picture quality is very important to me though - is there any other way?

Comment: If the TV supports being connected  NAS that could be a possibility.

Comment: Split the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd test ahead of the actual event.  Different TVs have different capabilities.

Another possible option would be to put a streaming media device (Chromecast, Intel Media Stick, etc.) into the TV's HDMI port and stream the video from another device (phone, tablet, or laptop); then, the other device's file size limit would apply (got a Macbook?).  Or you could use a compatible HDMI cable to play direct from the portable device.

Prior testing is still a very, very good idea.

Comment: Yeah, testing ahead would have been a good idea. I was hoping there was some standard that I hadn't heard of, but apparently not. I'll try to get a handful of options ready, and hope that at least one works out.

Comment: IMO, the one most likely to work well without ability to test ahead would be a Mac or Linux laptop (verified to play the specific video well, without hanging, etc.) with an HDMI cable or converter; you can test on your own TV to be sure the HDMI output is working as desired.  You should be able to get the cable you need at a local computer store, in stock.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm leaning towards. A laptop with the file and an HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

The question cannot be answered without more specific details on the TV brand and model. Knowing the brand and model will give you the information you need: specifically, what file formats, image resolutions, and file systems the TV and the USB port can handle.  If the TV is capable of handling the video's resolution and can handle something other than FAT or FAT32, then you should be able to do what you want.

HOWEVER, keep in mind that the USB port OR the USB drive itself might not be able to handle the sustained bandwidth necessary for playing 1920x1080P, especially at high frame rates. Again, check the manufacturer's specs on the TV and then check the specs for your flash drive.